# Specific table in SQL Server database is unreadable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can read (`SELECT`) from all tables in my SQL Server 2008 database except for one.

What could be reason for this behavior and how would one go about resolving it?

I had to resort to shutting down and restarting SQL Server.

EDIT: And yes, I have permission to read it -- I usually do so with no issue.

Comment: Once I have the same issue, it was a problem of memory (the machine has no free space even to do a simple select).. Anyway, I don't think that's your problem. Before you could do selects in the tables? I mean, the user has the permissions, grants, etc?

Comment: gives you any error ? Do you see the table?

Comment: Have you run [DBCC CHECKTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174338.aspx) against that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any application which is accessing this table continuously and locking it?

What is the size of this table, I mean how many rows?

Else I guess some bad sectors on disk where this table pages have been created.